# MeSH dataset not loading in dotNetRDF

Tags: rdf, jena, dotnetrdf

It's being more than 12hrs, I am loading mesh.nt (Medical Subjects Heading) RDF dataset using dotNetRDF, but no success yet. In Java (Apache Jena) it took 249sec. Here I am enclosing my code.

```
        IGraph g = new Graph();
        NTriplesParser ntparser;
        Console.WriteLine("RDF DS-2 Loading Started:");
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Started @: " + startTime.ToShortTimeString());
        try
        {

            ntparser = new NTriplesParser();

            //Load using Filename
            ntparser.Load(g, inputFile);
        }
        catch (RdfParseException parseEx)
        {
         
            Console.WriteLine("Parser Error");
            Console.WriteLine(parseEx.Message);
        }
        catch (RdfException rdfEx)
        {
         
            Console.WriteLine("RDF Error");
            Console.WriteLine(rdfEx.Message);
        }
```

Please let me am I doing something wrong? Secondly, queries are inference related so how would I add an inference parameter in it at the time of query execution, as it worked in java by declaring this line

```
QueryEngineHTTP qe1 = new QueryEngineHTTP("http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql", query1 );
qe1.addParam("inference", "true");
```

Thank you

Comment: this inference param is just a feature of the triple store. If dotnetrdf doesn't support inference  you simply don't have this feature. It's also very unspecific to require inference. It depends on the expressivity of the reasoning support which also affects the efficiency and performance for sure.

Comment: did you really load the ontology in Jena or just this `QueryEngineHTTP` thing

Comment: yes I have loaded it in Jena, and it worked as I mentioned it took 249sec to load, and for the query, I used QueryEnginerHTTP with inference parameter, but I wonder that in dotNetRDF it's not loading even I left it for 12 hrs, but no response

Comment: The Jena QueryEngineHTTP class runs the query against the remote endpoint, not against anything loaded in memory. If you want to query the remote endpoint with dotNetRDF you can do that using the SparqlRemoteEndpoint class (https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Querying-With-SPARQL#remote-query) without havnig to load anything locally into memory. MeSH is really big and to load it all into memory is going to require lots of RAM!

Comment: @bamboat_3 how did you load it into Jena? In an in-memory model or the TDB triple store? when you load it into Jena, why are you using `QueryEnginerHTTP` afterwards which does not query the local data but the remote SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: If you are going to ask a question of the form "Works in X but doesn't work in Y" then you need to show both the working and non-working code.  Otherwise as others have indicated there is no way of knowing if you are even doing the same things in both frameworks nor can we see what your expected successful behaviour should be